# Can't stringify MongoDB Date field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

My app is running on Node, MongoDB and Handlebars. Im trying to get user registration from MongoDB `timeCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }` field and change its format. It's a Date type field, so javascript methods may apply, but i'm getting an error.

I have several queries which I put into array

```
'use strict';

exports.init = function(req, res, next){

  var outcome = [];

  var getRegistration = function (callback) {
    req.app.db.models.User.find({ _id: { $eq: req.user.id } }, {_id: 0, timeCreated: 1})
    .exec(function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err, null);
      }
      outcome.user = user;
      return callback(null, 'done');
    });
  };


/* more queries */


  var asyncFinally = function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    res.render('adminpanel/account/index', {
      account: outcome.account,
      accountGroups : outcome.accountGroups,
      adminGroups : outcome.adminGroups,
      user : outcome.user
    });
  };

  require('async').parallel(
    [/* other queries */  getRegistration], asyncFinally
    );
};
```

and then output them using `each` helper

```
  {{#each user}}
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Joined</div>
      <div class="panel-body"> {{this.timeCreated}} </a></div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
```

This works ok, but when I'm trying to apply `toDateString` in a query `outcome.user = user.toDateString();`,  I get

```
TypeError: user.toDateString is not a function
```

What I get is not a string, and have similar error when I try to use `substr` without turinig it to a string.
What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Because you are turning the whole object into a string `outcome.user = user.toString();` Don't do that. Just pass in the object instead: `outcome.user = user`

Comment: @Neil Lunn Sorry I forgot to remove that from the code. That's what I did from the beginning and it worked, but what I need is to format that field and this is where I get an error. Fixing it now.

Comment: The reason of `ypeError: user.toDateString` is because you are turning `user` into a "string". The "string" has no such method. Also the result of `.find()` is an "array" so you should be using `.findOne()` instead for a "single" object. Then when you actually accessing the property it would be something like `user.timeCreated.toDateString()`, but really it's JavaScript so it's just going to stringify anyway. That's just the tip of the iceberg in the number of errors here. And since you don't include the full code, there is likely much much more.

Comment: I have other queries with multiple fields and from different models, and I decided to put them into one array. If you say that what I get is already a string it has to be no problem to use, for example  `user.substr(0,10)`, but what I get is the `TypeError user.substr is not a function`. Maybe it has something to do with getting different field types into one array? Or maybe I have to use an empty object for single-fielded queries?

Comment: You need to minize your code down to one action at a time and step through it to see what you are doing wrong. The problem here is you wrote in too many things and there are problems in all of them. You don't **ever** need to call `.toString()` and you need to understand why first. Start again with a smaller example is the best advice I can give. That way to can find your errors and learn. You cannot expect people to debug the whole listing for you. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)